# PHP Uploading: Uploading multiple files?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I'm currently uploading a single file successfully with the following form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 

<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And with the following script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);



    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";


        $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        if ($moved) {
            echo "Move: Success <br/>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Move Failed <br/>";
        }


          echo "Stored in: " . "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }

    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
    ?>
```

I'm now trying to allow the user to select three different files from the form.  I've found a few guides that show how to do something similar, but I can't quite get it working.

I've modified the form as follows (to include three inputs):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But I'm not sure how to modify the php to handle all three files.  I know I need to iterate through _FILES but everything I've tried isn't working.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each file element must have a unique name, or use PHP's array shorthand:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

or

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

Remember - the `name` attribute defines how you'll identify that field on the server, and if you use the same name multiple times, PHP will overwrite previous copies with the latest one as it parses through the submitted data. The array notation (`[]`) tells PHP that you INTENDED to have multiple fields with the same name, and that each copy it finds should be added to an array, not overwritten.

For the unique name version, you'd handle each as you are right now with the single file.

For the array version, PHP has a design stupidity that requires slightly different handling. You end up with a $_FILES array that looks like

```
$_FILES = array(
    'fieldname' => array(
         'name' => array(
             0 => 'first file',
             1 => 'second file',
             etc...
         )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
<input name="file" />
```

to

```
<input name="file[]" />
```

To make them into an array.

Then in your script, you reference them as:

```
$_FILES['file']['name'][0]; // first file
$_FILES['file']['name'][1]; // second file
```

Note you can replace name with any of the other file properties that you usually would use on a single file (e.g. size, type etc).

---

Alternatively, you can give them all different names:

```
<input name="firstfile" />
<input name="secondfile" />
```

Then in your script:

```
$_FILES['firstfile']; // first file
$_FILES['secondfile']; // second file
```

Comment: PHP file data goes into $_FILES, not $_POST. And referring to the uploaded files is vastly different (structurally) for the array version than for single-named files. It'd be $_FILES['file']['name'][0]

Comment: Still the wrong structure though. What you've got would be fine for one-file-per-field-name, but not for the array version.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks guys.  I ended up doing the file1/file2/file3 and then wrapped the upload in a for loop.

Comment: @Marc B - can you explain more about the array version??

Comment: Ah - have corrected it now the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) explain everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple file in single input like this..

```
<input type="file" name="pic[]" id="pic" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"/>
```

This input box can accept multiple files by pressing control key. Now you can access them in php like this

```
$_FILES['file']['name'][0]; // first file
$_FILES['file']['name'][1]; // second file
```

Answer (score 1):

KISS Code with some explanations:

There is fully functional simple code below to get you started. You can add error checking, max size stuff etc after you get something simple working.

The $_FILES array is a 3 dimensional array built into PHP, and that's where all the uploaded file info is stored.

There will only be ONE element for each 'name=' part of the HTML INPUT tag.

So if your INPUT tag looks like this:

```
<INPUT name="InpFile[]" type="file" />
```

The $_FILES array will have one top array element named 'InpFile'.

Also notice the [] after the InpFile.....that tells PHP that each time you use an input tag with that same 'name' it will add it to that same $_FILES array top element.

Within that one element there are 5 other array elements with the names: 'name', 'type', 'tmp_name', 'error', and 'size'.

And each one of those array elements will contain the data for each file that is uploaded.

Your first uploaded file name will be in $_FILES ['InpFile']['name']['0']

And the other info about your first uploaded file will also be in the array the same way, for example the size of the first file will be in $_FILES ['InpFile']['size']['0']

Each subsequent file name will be in $_FILES ['InpFile']['name'][1], $_FILES ['InpFile']['name'][2]....etc

After your upload, each file will have a random temporary name in the $_FILES ['InpFile']['tmp_name'][0...n] element, which is the name that it uses to first upload the files to a temporary area.

SO, after you upload, you have to move the files from the temporary area to where you want them.

That is done with this statement:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['InpFile']['tmp_name'][$Key],  
    $_FILES['InpFile']['name'][$Key] ) 
        or die("Move from Temp area failed");
```

In the foreach statement below, $Key and $Name are only there so that $Key will get assigned increasing numbers for each iteration...i.e. 0, 1, 2.....etc, and that you can then use $Key to reference the name, tmp_name, etc of each file in the array.

This code lets you do it all on one page, since the form actually calls itself (action="") to post. So the first time the page is loaded, you would get an error in the php code because $_FILES hasn't been set yet......so all the code is in an If statement: If ($_FILES).

After you submit the form, it will do it's thing and then echo a status for each file after it's been moved to your area.

Also, this code will upload the file to the same directory the page is in...you can change all that using info from other posts on SO.

```
    <FORM action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <P align="center"><B>Choose Files</B><BR>
      <BR>
      File One: 
      <INPUT name="InpFile[]" type="file" />
      <BR>
      <BR>
      File Two: 
      <INPUT name="InpFile[]" type="file" />
      <BR>
    </P>
    <P align="center"><BR>
      <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="UpLoad">
    </P>
 </FORM>
  <H3 align="center">&nbsp;</H3>
  <H3 align="center">Status:</H3>
  <P align="center">&nbsp;</P>
  <P align="center">
```

Put this PHP Code right here on the same page:

```
<?php
If ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES ['InpFile']['name'] as $Key => $Name) {
        move_uploaded_file(
          $_FILES['InpFile']['tmp_name'][$Key], 
          $_FILES['InpFile']['name'][$Key] 
        ) or die("Move from Temp area Failed");
        $EFileName = $_FILES['InpFile']['name'][$Key];
        echo "<P>$EFileName: Uploaded";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of the `name` attribute in the HTML side to `file[]` and then in PHP just iterate through `$_FILES['files']` and process each element as you normally would with a single file.