# Multiple image upload not moving file on directory

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to build a multiple image upload that takes the 3 submitted files from my form and stores them on my server.

I have the following but no matter what I receive "Invalid file" can anybdoy see where im going wrong?

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
 $aFile = $_FILES['file'][$i];




    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $aFile["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($aFile["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($aFile["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($aFile["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($aFile["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($aFile["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($aFile["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " .$aFile["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {


        if (file_exists("upload/" . $aFile["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $aFile["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'],
          "upload/" . date('U')."-".$aFile["file"]["name"]);  // add a unique string to the uploaded filename so that it is unique.
          echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";

    }

}
```

** HTML **

```
<li>
    <label for="picture_1">picture 1 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
</li>
<li>
    <label for="picture_2">picture 2 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="picture_2">
</li>
<li>
    <label for="picture_3">picture 3 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="picture_3">
</li>
```

Comment: Check which boolean in the `if` statement is `false`? Debugging 101.

Comment: have u tried to upload a single file first?

Comment: Show your HTML. Your html input file name may be wrong.

Comment: Ive tried a single file and that works @arunu...

Comment: check this link.Its similar to ur problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761066/php-uploading-uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I guess, the main problem is your HTML element names and the names used in `$_FILES` cannot be matched, i.e., you used the first file input name "file". It should be "picture_1". And you used the index 0 to 2 on your file handling part. It should be 1 to 3 to match "picture_1", "picture_2" and "picture_3".

Note that your form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, otherwise your files will not be uploaded. Here is the correct one:

There are two approaches to implement this :
(1) Naming file inputs separately such as picture_1, picture_2, etc.
(2) Naming file inputs as a group such as `file[]`.

**APPROACH 1: Naming file inputs separately**

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <li>
        <label for="picture_1">picture 1 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="picture_1" id="picture_1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="picture_2">picture 2 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="picture_2" id="picture_2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="picture_3">picture 3 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="picture_3" id="picture_3" />
    </li>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(sizeof($_FILES)){ 
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
     $aFile = $_FILES['picture_'.$i];
     if(empty($aFile['tmp_name'])) continue; # skip for empty elements

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $aFile["name"]));
        if ((($aFile["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($aFile["size"] < 20000)
        && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($aFile["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " .$aFile["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {       
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $aFile["name"]))
              {
              echo $aFile["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], 
                "upload/" . date('U')."-".$aFile["name"]); 
              echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
              }
            }
          }
        else
        {
          echo "Invalid file";  
        }
    }
}
```

**APPROACH 2: Naming file inputs as a group**

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <li>
        <label for="picture_1">picture 1 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" id="picture_1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="picture_2">picture 2 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" id="picture_2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="picture_3">picture 3 : </label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" id="picture_3" />
    </li>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(sizeof($_FILES)){        
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $type       = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
        $tmp_name   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $error     = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
        $size       = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

        if(empty($name)) continue; # skip for empty element

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $name));
        if ((  ($type == "image/gif")
            || ($type == "image/jpeg")
            || ($type == "image/png")
            || ($type == "image/pjpeg"))
            && $size < 20000
            && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts) )
          {
          if ($error > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " .$error . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {               
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $name))
              {
              echo $aFile["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,
              "upload/" . date('U')."-".$name); 
              echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";      
        }       
    }
}
```

**CREDITS:**

- File extensions should be checked with lower cases using
  [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).
- If you use `<label for="some_id">`, you can
  have the same ID attribute in your respective HTML element, e.g., `<input
  type="file" name="..." id="some_id" />`. When you click the label, the **onclick** event of the element will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The file size is expressed in bytes.

One of the conditions is a filesize limit check: `($aFile["file"]["size"] < 20000)`

That's lowers the filesize limit to 20 KB.

It might just happen that you exceeded that limit.

Check the size of the files you are uploading.

**Update**

This is how the files structure looks like when submitting three upload fields:

```
array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
     'name' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'all_products (6).csv' (length=20)
          2 => string 'pricero (3).csv' (length=15)
          3 => string 'pricero.csv' (length=11)
      'type' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
          2 => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
          3 => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'E:\server\wamp\tmp\phpEF79.tmp' (length=30)
          2 => string 'E:\server\wamp\tmp\phpEF7A.tmp' (length=30)
          3 => string 'E:\server\wamp\tmp\phpEF7B.tmp' (length=30)
      'error' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => int 0
          2 => int 0
          3 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => int 29702
          2 => int 23095
          3 => int 23095
```

There is something wrong with your `$aFile` variable. I tried to run your script and got errors (Undefined index and the like).

Comment: are the file extensions containing uppercase letters? That also can be a problem. (My apologies, if you are a linux/unix user :))